# MySQL - UPDATE and DELETE QUERY not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-delete

I'm just a beginner in terms of programming, so I'm just referring all my codes through tutorials. Luckily, I found this online tutorial in youtube where users are allowed to add, update, and delete data in mysql using php. I follow all his instructions, I got it working but then it stopped when I added css on it.

This is not a general issue, I just need some help. If anyone can help me, much appreciated. Thank you so much.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "rssfeed";

    $connect = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$connect) {
        die("Connection failed. Error" . mysql_error());
    }

    $database = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connect);
    if (!$database) {
        die("Can't select database");
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM record";
    $data = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

    if (isset($_POST['update'])){
        $updateQuery = "UPDATE record SET name = '$_POST[name]', url = '$_POST[url]', description = '$_POST[desc]' WHERE name = '$_POST[hidden]'";
        mysql_query($updateQuery, $connect);
        header("Location: maintenance.php");
    };

    if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM record WHERE name = '$_POST[hidden]'";
        mysql_query($deleteQuery, $connect);
        header("Location: maintenance.php");
    };

    if (isset($_POST['add'])){
        $addQuery = "INSERT INTO record (name, url, description) VALUES ('$_POST[iName]', '$_POST[iUrl]', '$_POST[iDesc]')";
        mysql_query($addQuery, $connect);
        header("Location: maintenance.php");
    };


    echo "<div class=center>
        <table id=myTable border=1>
        <tr>
        <th> Name </th>
        <th> URL </th>
        <th> Description </th>
        </tr>";

    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
        echo "<form method=post action=maintenance.php>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=name id=name value=" . $record['name'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=url id=url value=" . $record['url'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<textarea rows=1 cols=50 wrap=physical name=desc id=desc>" . strip_tags($record['description']) . "</textarea></td>";
        echo "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['name'] . ">";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update id=update value=update" . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete id=delete value=delete" . " </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</form>";


    }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<form method=post action=maintenance.php>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=iName></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text id=url name=iUrl></input></td>";
        echo "<td><textarea rows=1 cols=50 name=iDesc></textarea></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=add id=add value=add" . " </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>";

    mysql_close($connect);
    ?>
```

Comment: You have 2 submits in 1 form, PHP doesn't like that. I suggest you take a look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054363/form-with-two-button-submit-with-different-value

Comment: @User8889 still doesn't work :(

Comment: Then try to approach it in another way. For example use url's instead of buttons like this <a href='maintenance.php?action=delete'> and then get the action like this: $_GET['action'] and then do your query

Answer (score 0):

In your queries, `$_POST[name]` should be `$_POST[\"name\"]`. BUT, this is terrible, you are very open to SQL injections.

Please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and stop using `mysql_query` (it's deprecated)

Comment: I thought it should be `$str = "{$_POST['name']}"`?

Comment: thanks for the info. I'm still new to mySql and unfortunately i still dont know how to use PDO :)

Answer (score 0):

you have several errors in your echo output..

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=name id=name value=" . $record['name'] . " </td>";
```

You have forgot the single quotes for each html-element-attribute and the bigger then at the end of multiple input elements...

try this:

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='" . $record['name'] . "'> </td>";
```

Comment: I did that before but still doesn't work. My add button works perfectly, just the update and delete button.